# LIKE query not working in android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a LIke query to get results from database according to user input in search box.

Below is the method I am using to get the results

```
public Cursor getSearchResults(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(myContext, "dhfhgjhfghdfjghxdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String[] args={query};

    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,chapter FROM chapters  WHERE chapter LIKE '%query%'", args));


}
```

Here the %query% is coming from search action im my searchResultActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.search_query_results);

mQueryText = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.txt_query);
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
 Intent intent = getIntent();

 String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
 Toast.makeText(SearchResultsActivity.this,query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  dbBookHelper = new BooklistHelper(this);
    ourCursor = dbBookHelper.getSearchResults(query);
    startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
    adapter = new AuthorAdapter1(ourCursor);
    mQueryText.setAdapter(adapter);

    //mQueryText.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);

    }
```

But i am getting this error "cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range android. the statement has 0 argument".
Please help me in this.
Let me know if you need more information.
Thanks In advance..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL doesn't have any `?` variable placeholders but you have one bind argument `query`.

Change the SQL to

```
SELECT _id,chapter FROM chapters  WHERE chapter LIKE '%' || ? || '%'
```

where `||` is string catenation operator in SQL.

Comment: Hi, This code is working, can u please tell me how can i display NO RESULTS FOUND " on my SearchResultActivity Screen if the Query string dosen't matches with any of in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] args= new String[]{query};
return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,chapter FROM chapters  WHERE chapter LIKE '% ? %'", args));
```

Comment: To declare an array that way in java you should do it like this `String[] args= new String[]{query};` you can see other ways of declaring arrays in here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1200646/1259923]